# Is it viable to earn in-game ISK to buy premium?

Tags: eve-online

I'm a new EVE-Online player and I've been wondering whether it's viable to earn enough ISK in-game on a regular basis to be able to pay for premium, and as or right now 500 PLEX costs currently at around 1.8bn ISK? Is this achievable or will this ruin the fun from the game? Also is the game fun in the long run without the premium access? Last but not least, do you have any advice for a newbie how to earn ISK? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Some of your questions here are subjective. It's tough to tell what would "ruin the fun of the game" for you. Also, I'm sure you'll find people that say the game is fun as an Alpha clone, only fun as an Omega clone, or not fun at all for any access. I suggest looking over the [Tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) and try to narrow your question down to something more objective.

Comment: A new player is unlikely to make enough ISK through grinding. Your skills and ships will be too bad. The only viable ways of making that kind of cash for the average player without specializing is to grind sites in nullsec or wh space. For veteran players you can make a fortune in various other ways too, including trading, crafting, scamming, pvp, PI, mining etc etc.

Comment: As for taking away the fun, the trick is to find something fun in the game to begin with. Once you do that, stick with it. Because most things in the game are very boring and grindy. Pretty much everything that isn't small gang pvp revolves around grinding at some extent (even small gang pvp can be grinding if you gate camp). It's one of the most grindy MMOs of all time for sure.

Answer (score 13):

I'm going to say that your question is subjective and depends on the kind of player that you are, as Ellesedil mentioned. It might be fun for one player to grind 20-30 hours per week for their monthly PLEX, and another player would absolutely despise it.

On that note I'll say that it is entirely possible for a new player to earn enough ISK in-game on a regular basis to afford the omega (premium) account. There are several ways of doing this, exploration and combat sites likely being the easiest to get started. As you become a more experienced player, it will become easier to make the ISK each month to pay the subscription.

Will you (the average new player) enjoy this? Will it be a rewarding and satisfying use of your time? Absolutely not. Think about it like working a second job, if you're spending 20 hours per week grinding for 2.4 billion that you exchange for the equivalent of $20 in real life currency -- you're cheating yourself. It would be a far more efficient use of your time to spend 1 hour in real life earning the $20 that might have taken you 40-60+ hours in-game. However, if the sense of reward you get from achieving the goal each month is a reward in itself, then the game has achieved its intent of being what it is, a game that's fun. What I would instead is take that 2.4 billion and use it to buy ships, skill injectors, etc. In my experience this makes the game far more enjoyable and opens up new opportunities.

You don't need the premium access to have fun in the game. Most of the content will be available to you as an alpha character. After you've played for around a year however, you'll definitely want to upgrade your account in order to join in activities that require more specialized ships and fits. Some more experienced groups will require you to be an omega character. If you're already spending countless hours each month playing the game, why not spend $15 to make your experience that much more enjoyable?

After 15 years of playing EVE, my advice for making ISK as a new player would be to 1. Do wormhole faction relic site exploration in c1, c2, c3 wormholes. You can easily make 200 million on a lucky day with a few hours grind. You will also learn the game mechanics well that way. If you want more action (or less depending on the perspective), I would recommend joining a nullsec alliance and starting in combat sites in a ship such as a navy vexor, or whatever meta fit people are using. You can also run highsec exploration combat sites, but it's more competitive. Regardless of which option you choose to make ISK, your ability to generate income scales with how engaged you are in learning from other players. Get involved with a player alliance or **experienced** corporation (a bigger one that does PvP) and they'll help you get started in the right way.

***Update 2024***
I don't like them, but Abyssal sites are one of the best ways to make isk now. Faction warfare has also been changed significantly, and is another great way to make isk. The other advice still holds true.

**TL;DR Q&A**

Q: I'm a new EVE-Online player and I've been wondering whether it's viable to earn enough ISK in-game on a regular basis to be able to pay for premium

A: Yes

Q: Is this achievable or will this ruin the fun from the game?

A: Depends on the player, it will likely take away from the fun.

Q: Also is the game fun in the long run without the premium access?

A: Yes, but you'll want it anyway

Q: Do you have any advice for a newbie how to earn ISK?

A: Join a corporation that can teach you how they make ISK.

Answer (score 1):

Public incursion groups let you make roughly 100-120mil ISK/h with a steep entry level (specific battleship fits that might cost you maybe 200-300mil ISK. Very repetitive and mindnumbing but might teach you a few things about partaking in and commanding fleets along the way. This is a total of (at worst) 20 hours a month just to have a premium account.

Comment: Worth noting two things: 1) This was two years back or so so this answer might be outdated. 2) You'll appreciate having a job instead of doing incursions. That's 20h of your life for what, 5-10 bucks?

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Skill Farming](https://wiki.eveuniversity.org/Skill_Farming#Return) where you don't actually need to log into a character except for the occasional maintenance to passively fund your account.